# Highcharts histogram - use cumulative column percentages to plot Spline

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to plot a histogram. You can view the current example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/5o73tccm/4/

```
var data = [35,337,84,80,54,171,73,86,109,77,99,64,128,73,62,65,87,31,60,50,99,82,191,97,91,47,94,87,107,78,77,79,110,84,257,71,95,137,100,133,76,62,36,41,27,106,181,99,40,100,150,113,196,45,167,82,68,37,63,48,83,168,175,79,64,78,82,67,51,49,76,62,36,41,27,99,76,38,63,73,44,149,130,58,175,109,94,128,200,79,137,159,54,125,100,111,66,79,171,82,141,72,76,70,93,92,61,97,52];
var numItems = data.length;
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Title',
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: "12px"
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: [{
        title: { text: '' },
        opposite: true,
        alignTicks: false,
        visible: false
    }, {
        title: { text: 'Axis Data' },
        alignTicks: false,
        opposite: false,
        }],


yAxis: [{
    title: { text: '' },
    opposite: true,
    visible: false
}, {
    title: { text: 'Percentage' },
    opposite: false,
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            var number = ((this.value / numItems) * 100);

            return Highcharts.numberFormat(number, 1) + '%';
        }
    }
}],

series: [{
    name: 'Histogram',
    type: 'histogram',
    xAxis: 1,
    yAxis: 1,
    baseSeries: 's1',
    zIndex: -1,
    tooltip: {
        pointFormatter: function () {
            var number = ((this.y / numItems) * 100);
            return 'Number <b>' + this.y + '</b><br/>Percentage <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(number, 1) + ' %</b>';
        }
    }
}, {
    name: 'Data',
    type: 'scatter',
    data: data,
    id: 's1',
    marker: {
        radius: 0
    }
    }]
});
```

Hovering over each column gives a percentage value for that column relative to the overall dataset. In this case it is:

1.8% / 20.2% / 38.5% / 18.3% / 9.2% / 7.3% / 2.8% / 0.9% / 0.9%

I am looking to add a spline chart display to this graph :

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/spline-chart

Using a cumulative figure based on the addition of each of the above percentages so in this case the figures needed for the curved line would be:

0 / 1.8 / 22 / 60.5 / 78.8 / 88 / 95.3 / 98.1 / 99 / 100

As the raw data is being processed by HighCharts I am unsure how to get these percentage values from each column to use in the curved line for the spline display, so I am looking for advice on how to do this or if this is even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add series dynamically after the chart is loaded. Use [chart.addSeries()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeries) method on [chart load](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load) event.

You may want to add an extra xAxis which is linked to the histogram xAxis so the plotted spline will be centered according to the corresponded column.

Add series on load:

```
chart: {
  alignTicks: false,
    events: {
      load() {
        const histogram = this.get('h1')
        const cumulativeFrequency = [0]

        const cumulativePercentage = [{
            x: -histogram.binWidth / 2,
            y: 0
          }]
          .concat(
            histogram.points
            .map((point, i) => {
              const sum = cumulativeFrequency[i] + point.y

              cumulativeFrequency.push(sum)

              return {
                x: point.x + (point.x2 - point.x) / 2,
                y: Math.round(sum / numItems * 100 * 10) / 10,
                hx: point.x,
                hx2: point.x2
              }
            })
          )

        this.addSeries({
          type: 'spline',
          data: cumulativePercentage,
          yAxis: 1,
          xAxis: 2,
          tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '',
            pointFormatter() {
              const { hx, hx2 } = this.options
              const headerFormat = `<span style="font-size: 10px">${hx} - ${hx2}</span><br/>`
              const pointFormat = `<span style="color:${this.color}">\u25CF</span> ${this.series.name}: <b>${this.y}%</b><br/>`

              return headerFormat + pointFormat
            }
          }
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

Set an extra axis:

```
xAxis: [..., {
    linkedTo: 1
}],
```

---

### Live example and output

https://jsfiddle.net/yzskLxar/

[image: center spline]

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this, the answer is very helpful and almost perfect. An issue arises though when I test with some other data as per https://jsfiddle.net/h94oj75p/4/ Ideally I need the Y axis to be labelled 0 - 100% and the curve to plot at the correct levels so eventually it would reach the top of the graph. At present it seems to be plotting much lower down?

Comment: That is because the histogram has the scale which indicates the frequency number which do not range between 0 - 100 - basically you cover this by formatting labels. You might need a separate yaxis for the spline https://jsfiddle.net/nvsjhhak/ or preprocess the data for histogram